# Can a composer "master" package pull in dev-master packages without modifying minimum-stability

Tags: composer-php

I want to achieve the following setup (I've omitted other dependencies and stuff for clarity):

Project's *composer.json*

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/masterpackage": "*"
    }
}
```

Master package's *composer.json*

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/package-1": "dev-master",
        "vendor/package-2": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

The master package is versioned with releases, child packages are not, hence the dev-master requirement.

Since `minimum-stability` can only be set in the root composer.json and is applied to all dependencies (which is undesired in my case), is it possible to set a `dev`-stability flag for **only** the master package AND its own dependencies so that its child packages get installed properly? I've already tried `"vendor/masterpackage": "*@dev"` but to no avail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to get this working and thought it would be beneficial to post it as an answer for future reference.

Project's *composer.json*

```
{
    "require": {
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "dev-master",
        "vendorname/masterpackage": "*"
    },
    "merge-plugin": {
        "require": [
            "vendor/vendorname/masterpackage/dev-composer.json"
        ]
    }
}
```

Master package's *dev-composer.json*

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendorname/package-1": "dev-master@dev",
        "vendorname/package-2": "dev-master@dev"
    }
}
```

The merge plugin makes this working since it treats dependencies of specified JSON files as if they are in the root composer.json

Answer (score 0):

The way you experiment with it, it will not work.

The dependencies of depended packages cannot be influenced directly. So if your project prohibits development packages, you are out of luck.

You'd can add these indirect packages into your projects `composer.json`, adding them with the necessary `@dev` or `dev-X` surroundings. That way the will be required directly, allowing for development stability, and the master package requirement will also be fulfilled.

However, be warned that depending on branches is a very very bad habit and makes your dependencies very brittle. The commit id that has been used is recorded, but once you update and it goes wrong, you'll have a hard time juggling all the moving parts, i.e. all repositories that are only providing a branch.